# Autobuild Sphinx+Doxygen documentation on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages, python-sphinx, doxygen

My documentation is located in `/docs` on `master` branch. Sphinx is set up to store built docs in `/docs/build` folder (sources are in `/docs/source`). How do I setup GitHub pages to autobuild my docs with every push?

P.S: Storing built pages in `/docs/build` on `master` or in `/` on `gh-pages` both OK.

Comment: Dd you do a search on the internet for e.g: github actions sphinx doxygen

Comment: Internet? Is it a JavaScrips framework or something?.. Of course I googled some articles, but didn't found the one that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 4 GitHub Actions that helped me with it.

1. [Doxygen Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/doxygen-action) to extract doxygen documentation
2. [Sphinx Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/sphinx-build) to build sphinx documentation (it even understands pythons' `requirements.txt`)
3. [Upload Artifact](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/upload-a-build-artifact) to store builded docs
4. [GitHub Push](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-push) to push changes to `gh-pages`

Actually, I found using GitHub Actions quite convenient. There are a lot of pre-made tools that are quite good and easy to understand.

P.S: my code for workflow can be found [here](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-push). Feel free to use it.